# add extra field to ModelForm

Tags: django, forms, modelform

I am adding an extra field to a Django ModelForm like that:

```
class form(forms.ModelForm):
    extra_field = forms.CharField(label='Name of Institution')
    class Meta:
        model = db_institutionInstitution
        fields = ['conn_kind','time','inst_name2']
```

The form is actually working fine, but I cant prepopulate it. I use it in a `modelformset_factory`:

```
formset = modelformset_factory(db_institutionInstitution,form=form)
```

I manually run through a queryset and add the entry in the dictionary needed for the additional form in the formset. However, when I call:

```
formset1 = formset(prefix='brch',queryset=qs1)
```

the `extra_field` is not prepopulated as intended (the rest is working fine).

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to set a default.

```
extra_field = forms.CharField(label='Name of Institution', initial="harvard")
```

If you want to dynamically set a value put it on form initialization:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['extra_field'].initial = "harvard"
```

Comment: "default" should be "initial"

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'django.forms' has no attribute 'Charfield'`. Anyone knows how this answer will work in django 2.1?

Comment: Has 'CharField'

Comment: if i do this my `form.is_valid()` always return false